# Unable to instanciate object within phpunit testdirectory

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I'm trying to figure out phpunit, but i keep getting the following error when I try instanciate an object within the tesfile:

`Fatal error: Class stats\Baseball not found in c:\xampp\htdocs\stats\Test\BaseballTest.php`

I have the follow structure:

**root/Baseball.php**

```
namespace stats;

class Baseball {
    //some code
}
```

**root/phpunit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./Test/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

**root/Test/BaseballTest.php**

```
namespace stats\Test;

use stats\Baseball;

class BaseballTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
     $baseball = new Baseball(); // doesn't work
}
```

**root/composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "stats": ""
        }
    }
}
```

(The stats folder is the root.)

It seems to work fine when i move `BaseballTest.php` out of the test folder and put it in to the root directory. I am making use of composer to execute

Would be great if you guys could help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current directory layout and the composer configuration the `Baseball` class should be in the `stats` directory.

You can keep it in your root directory, but you'd need to switch to the `psr-4` autoloader, which lets you to skip directories included in the namespace map:

```
{
    "require": {
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "stats\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Trailing slashes at the name of the namespace prefix are important (`stats\\`).

More about autoloading standards:

- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/
- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/
- https://seld.be/notes/psr-4-autoloading-support-in-composer

I also recommend you use a more standard directory layout. Put your classes into the `src` directory, and your tests into `tests` directory. Namespaces are mostly uppercased. Here's how it could look like:

```php
<?php
// src/Baseball.php

namespace Stats;

class Baseball
{
}
```

```php
<?php
// tests/BaseballTest.php

namespace Stats\Tests;

use Stats\Baseball;

class BaseballTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testIt()
    {
        $baseball = new Baseball();
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

```
{
    "require": {
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Stats\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Stats\\Tests\\": "tests"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!